# Converting an image to Doc

Tags: opencv, jakarta-ee, tesseract

I am trying to make an application which make a editable document file(doc or pdf) from an image. I am planning to use tesseract for extraction of the text. But i am not yet sure how to get the basic formatting of the text(size,bold,italic,underline) & images that might be present in the document image. I am planning to use J2EE, to make a Web Based App(Have to use J2EE). I think i might be able to recognize the components and formatting of the document using OpenCV, but i am not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are planning to use Tesseract for the basic OCR capabilities, try looking into the hORC formatted output. That includes quite a lot of additional information about font-size, font-face, position, etc.

You can find a description of hOCR here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QQnIQtvdAC_8n92-LhwPcjtAUFwBlzE8EWnKAxlgVf0/preview#heading=h.e903b9bca924

If that doesn't work out, it depends on how much effort you want to put into Tesseract. It's internal APIs (available in Java via Tess4J, among others) do provide much of the information that you would need to reconstruct the page layout.